# Accessing private instance method from within the class

Tags: objective-c

I have an instance method that isn't declared in the header file (private) that i still want to use from any other instance method in that class for example

Header with public methods

```c
@interface Tap : NSObject

- (void)enable;
- (void)disable;

@end
```

Class Impl

```c
@implementation Tap

- (CGEventRef)callback:(CGEventTapProxy)proxy :(CGEventType)type :(CGEventRef)event :(void *)context {
  ...
}

- (void)enable {
  CGEventTapCreate(tap, place, options, mask, /* How to pass the callback here? */, context);
}

...

@end
```

it seems like i can't just use something like `self.callback`, so how can i pass this method to the EventTap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem mixing C in your implementation

```
CGEventRef eventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    
    // when userinfo is used as reference to the object
    Tap *tap = (__bridge Tap *)refcon;
    [tap exampleMethod];

    // your logic here ..
    
    return event;
}

- (void)enable {
    void *userinfo = (__bridge void *)(self);
    CGEventTapCreate(tap, place, options, mask, (CGEventTapCallBack)eventCallback, userinfo);
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to access to `self` in the callback? I still want access to the instance

Comment: `self` in objC refers always to public methods, there are no real private methods.
In C functions are pointers and in objC they are methods called @selector of type SEL. You can pass around selectors or you define a protocol for later use as delegate definition. CGEventTapCreate is an C api so its much easier going with it then lifting it into objc.

Comment: updated the answer so you see how to pass a reference to the object where you expect to find methods to call from. This is the reason why CGEventTapCallback is used as type, so your TapCreate can pass the right thing to *refcon when calling.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to achieve, thanks for the detailed explanation